# nonstop iOS speech recognition?

Tags: ios, swift4, speech-to-text, speech

In one of my application I am using the Speech framework for converting user's voice into Text.

Basically I want my application hands-free with some commands It can operate.

So there is a limit of Apple that has only 1000 request per hour and SFSpeechRecognitionTask only last about 1 minute only.

I want SFSpeechRecognitionTask should make alive and keep recognise the voice. 
So what is the best way we can do with the code. Is it too much battery gain If I will do restart SFSpeechRecognitionTask in every 1 min?

I have done code like below to start detecting voice and it's going to stop after 1 minute.

Please help me out if there will be a way to achieve it.

```
func startRecording() {

        if recognitionTask != nil {
            recognitionTask?.cancel()
            recognitionTask = nil
        }

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
            try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
            try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        } catch {
            print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
        }

        recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()

        guard let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode else {
            fatalError("Audio engine has no input node")
        }

        guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else {
            fatalError("Unable to create an SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object")
        }

        recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true

        recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in

            var isFinal = false

            if result != nil {

                if self.speechTimer != nil
                {
                    if (self.speechTimer?.isValid)!
                    {
                        self.speechTimer?.invalidate()
                    }
                    self.speechTimer = nil;
                }
                print(result?.bestTranscription.formattedString as Any)

                self.speechTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: false, block: { (timer) in
                    print("Recognition task restart")
                })

                isFinal = (result?.isFinal)!
                if isFinal {
                    print("Final String: \(result?.bestTranscription.formattedString ?? "No string")")
                }
            }
        })

        let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
        inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer, when) in
            self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
        }

        audioEngine.prepare()

        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch {
            print("audioEngine couldn't start because of an error.")
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you try to circumvent Apple limits (where speech recognition cuts off after a minute or whatever they hard coded it to be), your app is going to get rejected.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann So is there any other way to do ? OR can I use another technology or SDK which will provide this functionality. I want to do anyhow

Comment: You need to design same default siri like mechanism so that you can achieve what you are trying to explore.

Comment: @CodeChanger , Is siri using Speech framework in background, is it possible siri is doing some wake up call in frequent time then only it can be detect "Hey Siri"? I don't think so if it is using this kind of mechanism otherwise siri will drain the battery. What is the exact mechanism it's using if have any idea about it?

Comment: Not exact same like Siri but you can implement like same as if voice frequency is lower than some min value you can stop speech recognization and start automatically after some time so what you are expecting end less recognization will work like this.